# Substracting an int from long long

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

```
if(number > 999999999)
{
    int n_billions;
    n_billions = number/1000000000;
    cout << number;

    number -= n_billions*1000000000;
    cout << number;
}
```

If I make number = 9000000000 (nine billions), I don't understand why after I run the program the variable `number` instead of being 0 is 8589934592.

Can it be that number is a `long long` type and n_billions is a `int`?

Comment: The short answer: yes. The long answer: yeeees.

Comment: `number -= n_billions*1000000000LL;`

Comment: But I asked before if I can substract a int to a long long and other people told me that the casting is automatic.

Comment: @Paolo : Yes, you can subtract an int from a long long, but you cannot necessarily store _the result_ into an int.

Comment: @PaoloCaponeri Consider the multiplication first. The left operand `n_billions` is an int and the right operand `1000000000` is also an  int. Nothing will be converted there and the multiplication will overflow the range of int.

Comment: So practically the value n_billions*1000000000 is first stored into the n_billions var and then substracted to number?

Comment: By default integer literals, like 9000000000, are type int.  And if it is too big for an int it gets truncated. Use 9000000000LL to make the constant type long long.

Comment: aaaaaah ok. Thank you very much, now I understand. Even if the number is not a variable I still have to specify if it's a long long. Thanks :)

Comment: Rather than multiplying and subtracting, you can use the **remainder** operator: `number = number % 1000000000`, which can be written more compactly as `number %= 1000000000;`.

Comment: You can subtract an integer from a long long. You can't multiply an integer with a very large number and expect not to get overflows. It doesn't get promoted to long long until AFTER the multiplication (unless you use casts, or add LL to the constant to make it a long long constant)

Comment: +1 because I am in disbelief that someone would downvote this question.  Not everyone can be an expert on computer mathematics in their first year at Cal Tech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that you multiply the number of billions by a long long, like this:

```
number -= n_billions*1000000000LL;
```

Otherwise, you get an integer overflow for `n_billions` greater than 2.

```
long long number = 9000000123LL;
if(number > 999999999) {
    int n_billions;
    n_billions = number/1000000000;
    cout << number << endl;

    number -= n_billions*1000000000LL;
    cout << number << endl;
}
```

The above [prints](http://ideone.com/irBm21) `123` as expected.

Of course this is equivalent to obtaining a *remainder*, like this:

```
number %= 1000000000;
```